# How to use expression for (click) event

Tags: angular

In Angular2 I have multiple buttons and on click they set a value. Is it possible to use expression in the click event ie., instead of calling a function can we set the value directly?

```
<button (click)="setValue(1)">1</button> 
<button (click)="setValue(1)">2</button>
<button (click)="setValue(1)">3</button>
```

to some thing like

```
<button (click)="{{value=1}}">1</button> 
<button (click)="{{value=1}}">2</button>
<button (click)="{{value=1}}">3</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use expressions but don't use `{{}}`

```
<button (click)="value=1">1</button>
```

Angular evaluates the value part when the attribute name is wrapped in `[]`, `()` (or both `[()]` **or** when the value contains `{{}}`. **Don't** use `[]` and `()` together with `{{}}`.

`{{}}` stringifies the result. If you want to bind non-string values to properties don't use `{{}}` at all.